# Effective Looping Checkup VBA

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007

**Summary:** My company has two different spreadsheets with many policies on each. They want me to match up policies by a policy ID and transfer all the old notes from the old spreadsheet to the new spreadsheet.

**Reasoning:** my issue is not with not understanding how to do this, but the BEST way to do this. Since joining StackOverflow I've been told things I should and shouldn't do. I've been told different times it is better to use a `For Each` loop instead of a simple `Do` loop. Also, I've been told I shouldn't use `.Select` heavily (but I do).

**How I Would Normally Do It:** I would normally just use a `Do` Loop and go through the data just selecting the data with `.Find` and using `ActiveCell` and when I wanted to interact with other Columns in that current row I would just use `ActiveCell.Offset()`. I tend to love `.Select` and use it all the time, however on this project I'm trying to push myself out of the box and maybe change some bad coding habits and start using what may be better.

**Question:** How would I go about doing the equivalent of an `ActiveCell.Offset()` when I'm using a `For Each` loop?

**My Code So Far:** **Questions/Criticisms welcome

```
Sub NoteTransfer()

    transferNotes

End Sub
Function transferNotes()

    Dim theColumn As Range
    Dim fromSheet As Worksheet
    Dim toSheet As Worksheet
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim lastRow As Integer

    Set fromSheet = Sheets("NotesFrom")
    Set toSheet = Sheets("NotesTo")

    With fromSheet                      'FINDING LAST ROW
        lastRow = .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    End With

    Set theColumn = fromSheet.Range("B5:B" & lastRow)

    For Each cell In theColumn          'CODE FOR EACH CELL IN COLUMN

        If cell.Text = "" Then

            'do nothing

        Else

            With toSheet         'WANT TO FIND DATA ON THE toSheet

                Cells.find(What:=cell.Text, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate



            End With


        End If

    Next cell

End Function
```

Example

[image: Example Picture for reference's sake]

Bottom of the sheet

[image: Bottom of the Sheet.]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, your question:

`Question: How would I go about doing the equivalent of an ActiveCell.Offset() when I'm using a For Each loop?`

Doesn't make much sense given the code you posted. It's a very general question, and would need some context to better understand. It really depends on your loop. If you are looping a contiguous range of cells from the ActiveCell then you could say ...

```
For each cel in Range
    myValue = ActiveCell.Offset(,i)
    i = i + 1
Next
```

To get the column next to each cell in the loop. But in general I wouldn't call that *great* programming. Like I said, context is important.

As far as your code goes, see if this makes sense. I've edited and commented to help you a bit. Oh yeah, good job not using `Select`!

```
Sub transferNotes() '-> first no need for a function, because you are not returning anything...
                       'and no need to use a sub to call a sub here as you don't pass variables,
                       'and you don't have a process you are trying to run

    Dim theColumn As Range, cell As Range '-> just a little cleaner, INMHO
    Dim fromSheet As Worksheet, toSheet As Worksheet '-> just a little cleaner, INMHO
    Dim lastRow As Integer

    Set fromSheet = Sheets("NotesFrom")
    Set toSheet = Sheets("NotesTo")

    With fromSheet ' -> put everything you do in the "fromSheet" in your With block

        lastRow = .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row 'FINDING LAST ROW
        Set theColumn = .Range("B5:B" & lastRow)

        theColumn.AutoFilter 1, "<>"

        Set theColumn = theColumn.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible) '-> now you are only looping through the cells are that are not blank, so it's more efficient

        For Each cell In theColumn

            '-> use of ActiveCell.Offset(), it's not ActiveCell.Offset(), but it uses Offset
            Dim myValue
            myValue = cell.Offset(, 1) '-> gets the cell value in the column to the right of the code


            'WANT TO FIND DATA ON THE toSheet
            toSheet.Cells.Find(What:=cell.Text, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate

        Next cell

    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: ah you answered the question whether you knew it or not with this: `Dim myValue
            myValue = cell.Offset(, 1) '-> gets the cell value in the column to the right of the code`

Also, Thanks for the recommendations and explanations. +1

Comment: what does this line do specifically?

`theColumn.AutoFitler 1, "<>"`

Comment: @MikeKellogg -> it filters out your range for any non-blank cells.

Comment: oh, ok so what specifically does this do then:
`theColumn.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)` ?

Comment: I got an "Object does not support this property or method" error on this line:
`theColumn.AutoFitler 1, "<>"`

Comment: @MikeKellogg -> Doh! I spelled `Fitler`, I meant to write `Filter` change to `theColumn.AutoFilter 1, "<>"`

Comment: I see now haha, however I still get "AutoFilter method or Range class failed" error though..any idea why?

Comment: Can you post a link to your workbook, or a dummy version of it?

Comment: It works for me. What's the value of `theColumn` at that point?

Comment: @Brad the value of the `theColumn` is `B5:B & lastRow`

Comment: That's what you tried to set it to but did that succeed? I mean to say, when you debug what is the actual reference? was it set successfully? is `LastRow` set? Something is not set somewhere in the sequence.

Comment: @MikeKellog -> Place a code break at `Set theColumn = .Range("B5:B" & lastRow)` Then in the Immediate Window, type ?lastRow. What is your result?

Comment: the `Dim lastRow As Integer` should probably be `Dim lastRow As Long` since we're referencing rows (which can exceed the capacity of `Integer`). Probably not the problem here though.

Comment: 688. It is the last cell in that column However, the chart actually goes down to 690.

Comment: @Brad Posted a picture of the bottom of the chart as well.

Comment: @MikeKellogg -> Dude, It's a pivot Table!!! Turns out that that is important information to leave out :) Haha... You cannot Filter on cells in a PivotTable except through the PivotTable methods / properties. That means you have to use PivotTables methods in your code, or write formulas in another column to get your data there and then use that column to filter.

Comment: @ScottHoltzman ugh, I thought that could possibly be a problem. However, I wrongfully assumed that it wouldn't interfere. I'm going to see if I can't just get text only since the pivot table is useless to me. sorry about that hehe

Comment: @Brad I ended up just copying everything and pasting values only to get rid of the pivot table. It works fine now. Thanks Scott and Brad!

Answer (score 1):

This is my suggestion so far.

```
Function transferNotes()

    Dim SourceColumn As Range
    Dim fromSheet As Worksheet
    Dim toSheet As Worksheet
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim lastRow As Long '<--changed to Long

    Set fromSheet = Sheets("NotesFrom")
    Set toSheet = Sheets("NotesTo")

    With fromSheet                      'FINDING LAST ROW
        lastRow = .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    End With

    Set SourceColumn = fromSheet.Range("B5:B" & lastRow)

    For Each cell In SourceColumn          'CODE FOR EACH CELL IN COLUMN
        If cell.Value = "" Then 'the .Text property can
                                'make for some confusing errors.
                                'Try to avoid it.
            'nothng to search for
        Else
            With toSheet         'WANT TO FIND DATA ON THE toSheet
                Dim destRng As Range

                Set destRng = .Range("A:A").Find(What:=cell.Value)
                If Not destRng Is Nothing Then
                    .Cells(destRng.Row, <your mapped column destination>)
                        = fromSheet.Cells(cell.Row,<your mapped column source>)
    ' you can either repeat the above line for all of your non-contiguous
    'sections of data you want to move from sheet to sheet
    '(i.e. if the two sheets are not arranged the same)
    'if the two sheets are aranged the same then change
    'the .cells call to call a range and include
    'the full width of columns
                Else
                    'nothing was found
                End If

            End With
        End If
    Next cell

End Function
```

Comment: instead of using `.Cells(destRng.Row, <your mapped column destination>)` Wouldn't it be easier to use `.Range("B" & destRng.Row)`?

Comment: Sure. I'm not aware of the difference for a small call like this. Although `.Range` allows you to reference multiple cells at once. So if you want to move `.Range("B" & destRng.Row & ":G" & destRng.Row) = fromSheet.Range(fromSheet.Cells(cell.Row,2), fromSheet.Cells(cell.row,6))` you can do it easier with the `Range` object. This line of code also illustrates the several options of referencing the same thing in different ways.

Comment: It's really whatever you're comfortable with. Now if you were making LOTS of nested `.` calls I'd say it might need some rethinking but nothing here is worth that kind of effort.